# Power Usage Profiling in Nsight?

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvidia, nsight

New to Nsight and GPU programming. I need a way to evaluate the affect my code has on power usage in the GPU.

This [article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cudacasts-episode-13-clock-power-thermal-profiling-nsight-eclipse-edition/) from 2013 shows that the feature was part of Nsight's toolset at some point, but I cannot find any references to power profiling in the modern toolset.

Does this feature still exist in any capacity in the modern Nsight toolset? If not, what is the recommended method of evaluating power consumption of GPU code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this feature still exist in any capacity in the modern Nsight toolset?

This feature is supported by the Visual Profiler and `nvprof`. Both these tools are supported up to NVIDIA Volta architecture.

> what is the recommended method of evaluating power consumption of GPU code?

You can use `nvidia-smi dmon` option `-s`/`--select`, if granularity in the range of seconds is sufficient. You could check `nvidia-smi dmon -h`.